# Super Simple Chat Demo, using PubNub is not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am making app in phonegap that requires chatting between the users of the app.I have used this link https://github.com/pubnub/cordova-plugin-demo
.I downloaded the zip, Build the apk and ipa file at build.phonegap.com but it displayes only the text box and send message button and when i click on it nothing happens .Can you tell how can i use it?Please help

Comment: any credentials required for that?

Comment: no credentials requirement is specified in this link